# combining implicit plots in R

Tags: r, plot

i have been trying to combine two or more impact plots in R but have not been able to do so. i am trying to create a phase space diagram. this is the code i have got so far

```
 r= 0.083
 ka= 100
 e= 0.3
 a= 1.2883
 t= 0.2313
 uj= 0.01
ua= 0.004
m= 0.005


 juvenile <- function(x,y){r*y*(1-y/ka)-(((1-e)*a*x*y)/(1+t*a*x))-(uj+m)+x}
 x<-seq(0,150,length=1000)
 y<-seq(0,150,length=1000)
 z<-outer(x,y,juvenile)
 a<-contour(x,y,z,level=0)



 adult <- function(x,y){m*x-ua*y}
 x<-seq(0,150,length=1000)
 y<-seq(0,150,length=1000)
 z<-outer(x,y,adult)
 b<-contour(x,y,z,level=0)`
```

is there a way of plotting them together?

Comment: can you specify "together"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
 a<-contour(x,y,z,level=0, xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y))
 b<-contour(x,y,z,level=0, xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y), add=TRUE)
```

Comment: @MandyBunke, if this resolved the issue, don't forget to indicate so by hitting the check mark